# Updating Mongo doc in scala using cashbah

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework

My sample doc in mongodb is:

```
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "sachin", "profilepic" : "images/pics/3.jpg" }
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "sumit", "profilepic" : "images/pics/2.jpg" }
```

I want to append status:0 to the doc whose name is "sachin".
I am new to scala. I write the code

```
val query1=MongoDBObject("name"->"sachin")
val query= MongoDBObject(status->0)
coll.update(query1,query)
```

But it doesn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this It worked fine for me

```
coll.update(query1,$set("status"->0))
```

Where query1 is your search query

Answer (score 0):

Simple googling will help here :). Here you have an example of finding the object:

```
coll.findOne(MongoDBObject("title" -> "Star Wars"))
```

and updating the object using its id:

```
coll.update(pfid, $set("year" -> 1994))
```

Full example you can find here: http://janxspirit.blogspot.com/2011/11/introduction-to-casbah-scala-mongodb.html

I'm sure you can find fully working examples on github, just clone, run and play with it.